# grep -v with perl one liner

Tags: bash, perl

Input is the multiple yaml files inside git:

e.g. config/conf/hosts/ghf04.lmn/engine-1.yaml

```
ports:
  ajp: 8010
  http: 8011
  shutdown: 8012
apps:
  - null
  - Michael
  - Hardy
```

I have something like this to extract the data under apps:

```
for j in a b
do
 for i in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
 do
     echo $j$i
                 ssh $j$i 'grep -P ".+(- .+)" abc/engine*yaml | perl -pe "s|\abc\/(ghf\d{2})\.lmn\/(engine-\d{1,2}).yaml:.+- (.+)|\1;\2;\3|g" |sort'

done # end CM
```

done

which gives me an output in the form of:

```
a04
ghf04;engine-1;null
ghf04;engine-1;Michael
ghf04;engine-1;Hardy
```

I want to remove lines containing null from the grep loop. So where do I put the grep -v in the perl command? Tried few things like below but didnt work:

```
ssh $j$i 'grep -P ".+(- .+)" abc/engine*yaml | perl -pe     "s|\abc\/(ghf\d{2})\.lmn\/(engine-\d{1,2}).yaml:.+- (.+)|\1;\2;\3|g" |grep -v ghf.+null |sort'
```

Comment: Perl is more than capable of handling this all by itself. Your question would be a lot clearer if you just showed some input, the desired output and your `grep | perl | sort` pipeline without the loops or the `ssh` part.

Comment: Input is a git yaml file something like:     
  apps: - null
            - Michael
            - Hardy

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us a small, representative sample.

Comment: To repeat Tom, use perl.

Comment: Right. So I want to know what can I use in perl to match a line that doesn't contain the word "null" (e.g. grep -v)

Comment: `perl -lne 'print unless /null/'` would do that but I don't think that it's the best way to solve your problem. You're better off writing a perl script that combines all of the things you're trying to do - if you're desperate to make it a one-liner, then it might be short enough to do so but I would personally recommend against it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky

```
find . -name *.yaml | xargs perl -e 'undef $/;for(@ARGV){open(FILE,$_),;$content=<FILE>;close(FILE);s/\.\w\w\w//g;s/^\.\///g;s/\//;/g;$content=~s/\s+-\s+null//g;$content=~s/ports.*apps:\n//sg;$content=~s/\s+-\s+(\w+)/\1 /g;@fields=split(/\s+/,$content);for $field(@fields){print "$_;$field\n";}}'
```